# Setting default value for Choice Column in Document Library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to use below commands for setting the default value for my choice column to "yes"  but it does not work using PnP Powershell. Can someone suggest me what am i missing here

Option 1;

```
Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues -List Documents -Field "Fully Executed" -Value "Yes"
```

Option 2

```
Set-PnPField -Identity "Fully Executed" -List "Documents" -Values @{DefaultValue="Yes"}
```

Comment: So, you are saying, you are looking at the SP GUI, and seeing this setting, not as you'd like it, then you leave the GUI to run a PS command to set this, then go back to the GUI to see if it's set?  So, just curious. If this is a one-off thing, then why script this at all? If you are looking at the GUI to review these settings, just use the GUI and set it directly. Automating is about something that has loads of steps, or stuff the is repetitive or CI/CD process, etc. Do you have the rights and privileges to do this?

Comment: Option1 is the way to do this as documented via [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpdefaultcolumnvalues?view=sharepoint-ps) and [other blogs](https://www.m365-dev.com/2019/07/24/sharepoint-library-folder-default-field-values/#:~:text=With%20a%20super%20simple%20Set-PnPDefaultColumnValues%20command%2C%20you%20can,is%20to%20set%20a%20managed%20metadata%20field%201).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Internal Name of the column, "Fully Executed" is the display name. It's internal name should be `Fully_x0020_Executed`.

You could check it in list settings-> click the column, you will see the internal name in the url:

[image]